# Where Is The Cmake Executable on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, qt-creator

Trying to create a plain c++ project in ubuntu using the the qt4 creator IDE. The wizard opens a dialog box and says "Please specify the path to the cmake exe".

Not sure where to look any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the future, you can use `which cmake` to find the path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm almost sure it's at its normal location: `/usr/bin/cmake`.

Comment: If you installed it with `apt`, this would be the normal location. If you didn't, probably not.

Answer (score 4):

You may not have CMake installed (it isn't by default in Ubuntu). Install it using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal location is /usr/local/bin/cmake

Comment: That is also what I get when using `which cmake` according to @SethMMorton's comment.

Comment: This depends on how you installed it. Packages you installed with `apt` will generally end up in `/usr` whereas hand-installed local packages go in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$locate cmake (installation file/path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to higher version than apt-get install cmake in ubuntu 16
https://apt.kitware.com

```
#install cmake 3.20.5  
wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kitware.gpg >/dev/null
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ xenial main'  
sudo apt update  
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DE19EB17684BA42D
sudo apt install cmake cmake-qt-gui cmake-curses-gui
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.